# Remake is skipping over the shell commands I want to debug

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, gnu-make

I've got a problem with the way I am shelling out. I'm working with Bash, but its on Debian Sid (Unstable) in a ARM64 Chroot. (I'm doing this because its our Debian package maintainer. Otherwise, I run away from the unstable, bleeding edge stuff)...

```sh
# echo $0
/bin/bash
```

It appears one of my shell commands is creating an `-o2` rather than an `-O2`. I suspect memory is being trashed while shelling out, and the `-o2` is just a symptom.

```sh
# make cryptlib.o
g++ -DNDEBUG -g3 -o2 -pipe -c cryptlib.cpp
```

Here's the same command under [Remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/remake.html/Debugging-Shell-Commands.html):

```sh
# remake -X -f GNUmakefile cryptlib.o
GNU Make 3.82+dbg0.9
Built for aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
...
Updating goal targets....
  File `cryptlib.o' does not exist.
  Must remake target `cryptlib.o'.
Invoking recipe from GNUmakefile:449 to update target `cryptlib.o'.
##>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
g++ -DNDEBUG -g3 -o2 -pipe -c cryptlib.cpp
##<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
++ (/cryptopp-git/GNUmakefile:448)
cryptlib.o
remake<0>
```

As can be seen, the stuff I am interested in has already passed. [Line 449](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/GNUmakefile#L449) is very uninteresting. Its just a standard recipe that uses `CXX`, `CXXFLAGS` and `$<`.

Unfortunately, I don't really see what I should be doing to debug this issue. According to [1.1.6 Debugging Shell Commands](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/remake.html/Debugging-Shell-Commands.html), there's a ***`step`***, but it does not really tell me how to use it. When I attempt to add it to the command:

```
remake -X step -f GNUmakefile cryptlib.o
```

It results in ***`No rule to make target 'step'`***.

How do I debug this makefile with Remake? Or even without it?

Comment: The recipe itself isn't involved with that flag's value. That's in a make variable. What is setting that is something inside the makefile itself. Do you have a `GNUMakefile.deps` file locally? Does `grep` find `-g3` or `-o2` anywhere in your source directory? Do you perhaps have `CXXFLAGS` defined in your environment?

Comment: I'll answer but only because of the "remake can't help here" information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recipe's in your makefile aren't involved with setting that variable's value.

That's is a make variable. It is set at make-parse time by make itself (and the make-level contents of your makefile).

I don't see anything in the linked `GNUMakefile` that says *either* `-o2` **or** `-g3` both of which are in the make-run compilation command.

That makefile does include a `GNUMakefile.deps` file if it exists. I suppose that might have the erroneous value in it. Do you have a GNUMakefile.deps file?

Does grep find -g3 or -o2 anywhere in your source directory? (In case there's some other included makefile?)

The last place that make might be getting this value from is the process environment (because `CXXFLAGS` is defined with the `?=` operator).

Do you have `CXXFLAGS` defined incorrectly in your environment?